# PHP $_FILES array corrupt, when empty contains invalid characters

Tags: php, arrays, forms

I have a lot of forms contained within a CMS I created. They have all been working fine up until today. The issue I am having is related to files being uploaded and the `$_FILES` array containing odd characters.

Contained within a form I have:

```
<tr>
    <td>Related PDF File:</td>
    <td><input type="file" name="pdfFile" size=50" value="<? pv($frm["pdfFile"]) ?>"></td>
</tr>
```

On submit it returns back to my script and I validate if the field has a file submitted:

```
if($_FILES['pdfFile']['name'] != '' && $_FILES['pdfFile']['error'] == 0) {
    $up_file->save($CFG->dirroot . "/docs/services/", "pdfFile", 1);
    $frm['pdfFile'] = $up_file->getFilename('pdfFile');
}
```

The issue is if I display my $_FILES array when the field has nothing submitted I get the following:

```
Array
(
    [pdfFile] => Array
        (
            [name] => ò…
            [type] => 
            [tmp_name] => 
            [error] => 4
            [size] => 0
        )
)
```

The `[name]` has some funky special characters within. Has anyone ever seen this? It is only happening on one of my servers. And if the input field actually has a submitted file, there is no issue.

Thanks in advance for any comments.

Comment: What's in `$frm["pdfFile"]`? By the way you can't set it like that. Otherwise you could upload files from a user's computer without the user knowing it.

Comment: Why are you trying to set the value of the input to whatever that is? Browsers usually ignore this since it would be a security hazard to allow pages to specify which file is to be uploaded.

Comment: I've seen that funky special character `ò` (as you name it), it's just a character. What's your problem with it?

Comment: $frm is array of values used throughout the form loaded from a database. This form is contained within a CMS with account privileges. You require access just to view this form.

Comment: I have seen this character many times, used in various languages. My question is why is it in my $_FILES array. I have removed the setting of the input as it is not required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out what the issue was. PHP was recently updated by our hosting provider to 5.3.8. There is a bug in this release which removes the first character in an uploaded file. You can see the bug here: [$_FILES 'name' missing first character after upload.](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=55510)

For some reason magic_quotes_gpc was set to on after the update. Turned it off, and all is good now.

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
[error] => 4
```

Using [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php):

```
UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE

    Value: 4; No file was uploaded.
```

Make sure u have `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute in your `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yes I have the correct enctype, and there was no file uploaded as the field was left blank. If I submit a file to be uploaded I have no issues.